# Trend: Linear or exponential

Tags: r, matlab, trend

I am trying to forecast data using ARIMA. I have read articles which say that I should first take the log of the series, if my series follows an exponential trend.

My question is: Is there a mathematical approach to find what kind of trend (linear or exponential) my data is following?

Im working with MATLAB and R. So any builtin functions would be really helpful.

Comment: You should start by simply plotting the data and seeing if there is any obvious trend. You can then share that plot with us and we can help form there.

Comment: I am trying to automate the process. So visual inspection is ruled out. I want the code to automatically check the type of trend and decide whether to automatically log the data or not.

Comment: Do both approaches and for each calculate the given result. Then use a measure to find the appropriate one. The measure, e.g., can be given by the prediction error found in a cross-validation procedure.

Comment: thank you.. that is a good idea.. but a lot of overhead... especially since I am already trying a lot of models with different values of p,q,P, and Q.
so i would still like to know if there is a proper approach to estimate if a trend is linear or not.